# Stacklight Prometheus Function not Working

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I am trying to get Prometheus Alerting UI to report in on two metrics

```
procstat_memory_vms{process_name="ovs-vswitchd"} / mem_total{host=~"cmp.*"}
```

From the above I get the good ol' "No data points found", however I need to try and find out how to find the ratio of the total process memory a VM consumes to the total memory on the compute host.

Basically whats in use by VMs / Total Compute Host Memory.

I have verified that both above are integers and the intersting thing is that both produce integer numbers...while if I use a fixed value for the

```
mem_total{host=~"cmp.*"}
```

It works, however I want to account for this dynamically without using a fixed value for the

```
mem_total{host=~"cmp.*"}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I guess you have a mismatch on labels. Have a look at [vector matching](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#vector-matching).

Comment: Thanks @MichaelDoubez, I think we found the issue.